# Angular 2 - How to pipe user input in HTML input tag with ReactiveFormGroup

Tags: angular, pipe, form-control

I am struggling to get user-inputted values formatted via a decimal pipe for Angular 2. Does anyone have an elegant workaround solution? My input is bound to a FormGroup via FormControlName.

For example if a user inputs "1000000" into an input field I would want to reformat it to 1,000,000 for the user to see but still preserve 1000000 on the actual control. I am looking for the behavior to limit the number of integer values as well as decimal places.

Comment: What you're looking for is Mask. You can learn something from the way PrimeNG doing their mask: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputmask

Answer (score 0):

To use a certain currency format you can use toLocaleString method, for instance:

```
var number = 3500000.78965736437;

console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-GB', { maximumFractionDigits: 2 }));
```

which is a Javascript method,

You can see all the local formats at http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/iso639.html

Here is the running Javascript example:
https://repl.it/KDvD/20

Answer (score 0):

yo can use a pipe

```
{{ '1000000' | number:'.2'}}
```

more info https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe